# How to get axios baseUrl in nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have axios module in my Nuxt.js project.
I also set up my baseUrl (for API) in `localhost:4040/api` while my client is running on port 3000.
When I fetch image data in the API, it returns a relative path to the api server which is like '/upload/1.png'

`{
    "src":"/upload/1.png"
}`

So, I need to get the axios baseUrl and concat it with it to make full path to the image.
Is there any way to do it other than hardcoding it?

Comment: what do you want to do with `"src":"/upload/1.png"`

Comment: @Helpinghand I want to display the image, since they run on different port (the api and the client), I can't use relative path

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If in **nuxt.config.js** you defined:

```
axios: {
  baseURL:"localhost:4040/api/"
}
```

All you need to do for the image is to point to it as follows:

```
:src="`${$axios.defaults.baseURL}upload/1.png`"
```

Comment: upvoted, very curious question if axios already has a baseUrl by default, why would you set it explicitly in nuxt config.js i have seen almost every piece of nuxt example do this

Answer (score 22):

You can access axios config like this to get your api base URL:

```
this.$axios.defaults.baseURL
```

Answer (score 16):

In case if someone is wondering how to make an axios baseURL domain-independent:

Here is how simply it can be achieved:

```
axios: {
  baseURL: '/'
}
```

It will work on `localhost:3000/api` as well as on `any-domain.com/api`

Comment: You save my hours man !!
thank you so much

Comment: This should have more upvotes. Handling baseUrl in nuxt at runtime is tedious indeed.

Comment: For me it calls `http:/api/user` when I try that >:-(

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.
My resolution step is as follows:
Delete folder .nuxt + remove cache in browser
Changer

```
  axios: {
     baseURL: 'http: // localhost: 8080/api'
   }
```

It works as expected. Before that, I tried a lot of ways like community tutorials but not effective.

Answer (score 1):

I had nuxt.config.js like this:

```
axios: {
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/api/",
},
```

in one of my components, I made an api call which responded like:

```
eachpost: {
   ....
   user: {
      ....,
      avatar: 'users/default.png'
   }
}
```

here avatar object has a relative path to my image, but in the client side, I must have the absolute path to the server.
so I wrote the below code in my component which worked successfully.
My absolute path to the photo was: **http://localhost:8000/storage/users/default.png**

```
<img :src="`${$axios.defaults.baseURL.slice(0,22)}storage/${eachPost.user.avatar}`" :alt="`${eachPost.user.name}`">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set base url for axios

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.example.com/';

so next time this url will be add with your required path for calling api

for details you can see from below link

https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score 0):

If someone intends to call axios, call it via dispatch store/index.js

```
   export const actions = {
     // nuxt server Init only works on store/index.js
     async nuxtServerInit ({dispatch}) {
         let response = await dispatch ('member / list', {page: 1});
         console.log (response);
       }
}
```

module file member.js

```
   async list ({commit}, payload) {
         return await this. $ axios. $ post ('/ user / list', payload) .then ((response) => {
             commit ('fetchSuccess', response);
             return response;
             })
             .catch (error => {
                 return error.response.data;
             });
     },
```

file nuxt.config.js config with axios  api

```
 axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:9020/api'
  },
```

Sorry if the answer is not appropriate but someone will need to hope that this explains them

Answer (score 0):

You just append `window.location.origin` with your axios url